# Xamarin PCL. Scrolling while Dragging

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

Is it possible to implement auto-scrolling when a user drags an item to the edge of visibible part of a CollectionView? Or StackLayout. Look's like there is no way to do this out of the box and no respective nuget packages exist. I've tried to implement this myself, but couldn't figure out which methods to override and for which of the entities. `DragGestureRecognizer` seemed to be promising, but still- no luck.

Comment: I did a test on IOS with DragGestureRecognizer and it works fine, so did you test on android?

Comment: Could you share your code? Indeed I've tested on android. Unfortunatelly I have no opportunity to check it on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the codes I used,drag one item to the edge and the list will scroll until reach the last item.

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PeopleViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
<CollectionView x:Name="mycol" ItemsSource="{Binding pgs}">
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="LightPink">
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Large">
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <DragGestureRecognizer DragStarting="OnDragstarting"/>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
        </Frame>
</DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
</Frame>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I've created the new project from Flyout template and tried this code. Doesn't work. Maybe there are issues with Xamarin version? I use 5.0.0.2196 and test on Android 9. What versions do you have?

Comment: I tested it on ios, I think android will need another workaround

Comment: @vlad did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: unfortunately- I haven't